# Submit on Radio button change

Tags: html, radio-button

How can it be done to submit when i change radio button from On to Off or from Off to On. My HTML code is :)

```
<div class="centered3">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="oralive-csv.php" method="post" name="fshi_shkruaj">
        <td><input style="margin-bottom:10px; float:right;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Shko Live" /></td>                          
        <table style="width:950px;">
             <tr>
               <th style="float:left;color:#900;">Titulli</th>
               <th style="color:#900;">Nentitulli</th>
               <th style="color:#900;">Live</th>
             </tr>
             <?php $i=0; foreach ($results as $result) : ?>
             <tr>
               <td style="padding-right:5px;height:1.5em;">
               <input type="hidden" name="id<?php echo $i; ?>"value="<?php echo $result['id'] ?>" />
               <input type="hidden" name="title<?php echo $i;?>"value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['text'],ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');?>" />
               <div class="textndrysho"><input style="font-size:16px;color:#000;width:200px;" type="text" name="title<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['text'],ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>" maxlength="32"/>
               </td></div>
               <td style="padding-right:5px;height:1.5em;">
               <input type="hidden" name="id<?php echo $i; ?>"value="<?php echo $result['id'] ?>" />
               <input type="hidden" name="subtitle<?php echo $i;?>"value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['subtext'],ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');?>" />
               <div class="textndrysho"><input style="font-size:16px;color:#000;width:400px;" type="text" name="subtitle<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['subtext'],ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>" maxlength="45"/>
               </td></div>
               <td style="padding-right:5px;height:1.5em;">
               <input type="hidden" name="id<?php echo $i; ?>"value="<?php echo $result['id'] ?>" />
               <input type="hidden" name="vendi<?php echo $i;?>"value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['vendi'],ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');?>" />
               <div class="textndrysho"><input style="font-size:16px;color:#000;width:120px;" type="text" name="vendi<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['vendi'],ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>" maxlength="12"/>
               </td></div>
               <td>
                <label><input type="radio" name="shfaq<?php echo $i; ?>" value="1" id="radiobuttonsondazh_0" <?php if($result['live']==1) echo 'checked'; ?> onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();" />Po</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="shfaq<?php echo $i; ?>" value="0" id="radiobuttonsondazh_1" <?php if($result['live']==0) echo 'checked'; ?> onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();" />Jo</label>            
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="chk<?php echo $i; ?>" >Fshi
               </td>
              </tr>
              <?php $i = $i+1;
                    endforeach;
               ?>
             <tr>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td><input style="margin-top:26px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Shko Live"  /></td>
             </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $i = $i-1; ?>" name="saka" />              </form>
    </div>
</div></center>
```

I have try it to onChange Submit this form but not lucky. :(
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: what wrong with ur code ?

Comment: Sounds like you need Javascript for that.

Comment: user1956570 i want to submit form when change radio button

Comment: Submitting a form on radio button change is bad for usability, as it strongly differs from normal behavior. Make sure you really want that, before addressing the technical question. And you can’t do this with HTML; you would need JavaScript, and the operation would be relatively simple—the code included in the question is mostly irrelevant to the issue (and it’s PHP code, not HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use some javascript it has special what they call event handlers. onclick, blclick, etc. There is a way to have javascript and php code mixed together. Maybe this would work. Also what do you want this form to do that way I can help you more easily.

```
function dosomething()
{
var formelement = document.getElementById['theid'].value; //retrieves the value from the form element
if (formelement == "whatever")
  {
  window.open("http://www139.net63.net"); //opens a url in a window
  }
  else
  {
  alert("This is a popup window");
   }
}
====================
<input type="radio" name="whatever" id="theid" value="your value, url etc." onclick="dosomething()">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can u help me with the full code please iam new on javascript functions ? :(

Comment: I updated it. What are you trying to make this code do (in specific)? That would help me to know what you need to to. I'm not especially good at javascript.

Comment: huh my comment I posted went away? I would like to know what you want this code to do in specific, that way I could answer your question more effectively. Also I'm not especially good at javascript.

Comment: <label><input type="radio" name="shfaq<?php echo $i; ?>" value="0" id="radiobuttonsondazh_1" <?php if($result['live']==0) echo 'checked'; ?> onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();" />Jo</label> 

I want to submit when i change radio button from On to Yes and from Yes to No